# how to get the values of variables php?

Tags: php

So I have:

```
 $first  = "one";
 $second = "two";
```

How can I get values of these variables in:

```
class TD
{
public $first;
public $second;

}
```

on the contrary, from here:

```
class TD
{
public $first = "one";
public $second = "two;

}
```

to here:

```
    $...   = ... ;
    $... = ... ;
```

need to then use it in the query(for ex.):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE cell = $first
```

Comment: If the provided solution worked please be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$td = new TD;

$first  = $td->first;
$second = $td->second;
```

The above variable `$td` is an instance of the class `TD` and it is accessing the classes properties, which are in this case `$first` and `$second`. Which is done like this `$td->first`. Learn all about [OOP in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Comment: Thank you, it works. Thank you for the link, I'll study. Have one more question, is there any difference in OOP between PHP5 & PHP7+ ?

Comment: @AndiCrew Yes, sure there are some differences like `Anonymous Classes` but generally it is the same. There are mostly just **inclusions** not **exclusions**

Answer (score 1):

you can also add a **constructor** and **pass** an **array** for **multi params**

```
class TD
{
    public $find = [];

    public function __construct($arr){
        foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
            $this->find[$k+1] = $v;
        }
    }
}

$array = ["one", "two", "tree"];
$td = new TD($array);

var_dump($td->find[1]);
var_dump($td->find[2]);
var_dump($td->find[3]);
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you, this is interesting, I'll try and use your option.

Comment: @Andi Crew I guess a Td can be variables on numbers or the class showed can only set 2 td's :(. So i hope that's help ;) gl for the next.